# JIRA. How to track the transitions between statuses of an object (issue)?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

**JIRA**

How to track the transitions between statuses of an object (issue) and record the time of finding tasks in a certain status?

The only idea that comes to mind right now is:

1. Create a custom field for the object.
2. Write a postfunction that will read the difference in the clip and write it to a specific field.

I think this method is not very beautiful, there are other suggestions?

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with programming issues. That makes this question off topic for stack overflow

Comment: Jira development have nothing to do with programming issues?

Comment: Really? The plugin is developed in JAVA language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually use code based on ChangeHistoryManager to get any changes.
Also pay attention to Script fields provided by ScriptRunner plugin.

Comment: It's good idea. One question, how get datetime in some status change? 

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/hYtsyv

Comment: Here is a code exmple to scan ChangeHistory for statuses: 'import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean

for(ChangeItemBean bean: ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager().getChangeItemsForField(issue, "status")){
     return bean.created
}'

Comment: One more question. I need to find the entry point to the plugin from this place. (Listener, function, etc.) so that the selected problems are remedied in the program and the code is already working with them. Any ideas?

screen: https://ibb.co/ivZhFa

Comment: Артём, тебе надо установить плагин ScriptRunner (он платный, но стоит своих денег). Потом создать новое поле с типом GroovyScript". Затем на вкладке плагина в разделе скриптовых полей вставить этот код.